# Cumulocity inventory filter

Tags: cumulocity

Is is possible to fetch inventory by more than one fragment type?

like

```
 inventory/managedObjects?fragmentType=c8y_IsDevice&fragmentType=c8y_DistanceSensor
```

and is possible to konow the list of available fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out the section "Query Language" on https://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/inventory. Your query would be:

`$filter=(has(c8y_IsDevice) or has(c8y_DistanceSensor))`

The query text needs to be encoded into valid HTTP query syntax (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). The encoded URL would be:

`/inventory/managedObjects?q=%24filter%3D(has(c8y_IsDevice)%2Bor%2Bhas(c8y_DistanceSensor))`

... which is a bit less readable. Note that queries using "or" tend to run slower.

You can currently not query for all available fragments in the system. This is something that can dynamically change at any time and can be extended by anyone.

Comment: for me, q=$filter=(has(c8y_DistanceSensor)) not working. Any reason?